# Whats the rule about a class handling its own instance?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this snippet of code in my code base:

```cpp
inline void Widget::setParent(Widget& roWidget)
{
   auto upoSelf = m_poParent->remove(*this);
   upoSelf->m_poParent = &roWidget;
   roWidget.m_aupoChildren.emplace_back(std::move(upoSelf));
}
```

In this situation, `upoSelf` is going to always be a `std::unique_ptr` to the object that `this` points to. So in essence, `Widget::setParent` has behaviour that handles the `Widget` object inside of its own function.

I'm wondering if there is any kind of UB or rules about how this works.

Comment: Is your concern that, even for a time, a member function of the object itself is touting around the unique pointer that owns it? How would this be any different than a non-member function doing *exactly* the same thing? Obviously the wheels blow off the wagon if `this` isn't really managed by a `std::unqiue_ptr<>`. But if that can be assured, there is no UB here. So long as your move semantics are intact, this works.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The `unique_ptr` is the only thing holding onto the object, so its not managed anywhere else and I believe the move semantics are correct in this case. The idea is to take the object out of its current parent and move it into the new parent. The object shouldnt be destructed anytime between those 2 operations.

Comment: It wouldn't be destroyed so long as everything you described (and I described previously) hold. All you're doing is moving a `std::unique_ptr` twice. The function you're doing it in isn't relevant. Fwiw, unrelated, I would manage the parent-relationship with weak pointers. Just something to think about. Good luck.